# How launch Qt Virtual keyboard only for Tablet Mode in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am making an application for Windows desktops and tablets. I need to launch Qt virtual keyboard in tablet mode.

I followed [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html) example in Qt docs

I just put one line of code in my main.cpp to get Qt virtual keyboard working

```
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
```

But now virtual keyboard launches in desktop mode also, which is not needed. How do I restrict the Qt virtual keyboard for tablet mode only?

I am using Qt 5.9 and tried 5.12. Windows on-screen keyboard does not launch all the time when needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For checking tablet mode you can use `bool QWindowsWindowFunctions::isTabletMode()` static function which is introduced in Qt 5.9. For enabling virtual keyboard in table mode and disabling in desktop mode you can periodically check it in a timer and show/hide `InputPanel` respectively:

```
InputPanel {
    id: inputPanel

    property bool enableKeyboard: false
    ...
    states: State {
        name: "visible"
        when: enableKeyboard && inputPanel.active
        PropertyChanges {
            target: inputPanel
            y: appContainer.height - inputPanel.height
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

`enableKeyboard` property is defined to activate/deactivate keyboard and it should be updated regularly using a `Timer` like:

```
Timer {
    onTriggered: enableKeyboard = utils.isTabletMode()
    running: true
    repeat: true
    interval: 1000
}
```

You should define `isTabletMode` function in a `QObject` based class like:

```
#include <QtPlatformHeaders/QWindowsWindowFunctions>
...
Q_INVOKABLE bool isTabletMode() {
     return QWindowsWindowFunctions::isTabletMode();
}
```

Do not forget to expose you class to qml by:

```
qmlengine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("utils", pointerToMyClass);
```